# When passing signer seeds in a CPI, is bump required?

Tags: anchor, cpi, bump

When passing signer seeds to a CPI like this:

```
    let seeds = &[
        b"whatever".as_ref(),
        &ctx.accounts.someacc.key().to_bytes()[..],
        &[bump]
    ];
    let signers_seeds = &[&seeds[..]];

    invoke_signed(&instruction, &account_infos, signers_seeds)?;
```

Noting that the bump is also passed in the instruction args

```
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
struct CpiArgs {
    bump: u8,
}

fn get_ix_data(bump: u8) -> Vec<u8> {
    let hash = get_function_hash("global", "init_account");
    let mut buf: Vec<u8> = vec![];
    buf.extend_from_slice(&hash);
    let args = CpiArgs { bump };
    args.serialize(&mut buf).unwrap();
    buf
}
```

With checks on the receiving end of the CPI (the ix this CPI is calling) like this:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(bump: u8)]
pub struct InitializeAccount<'info> {
    #[account(init,
        seeds = [
            b"whatever".as_ref(),
            someacc.key().as_ref(),
        ],
        bump,
        token::mint = some_mint,
        token::authority = some_auth,
        payer = owner)]
    pub some_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
// someacc and others...
}
```

I noticed that for some key combinations, this will fail with `Could not create program address with signer seeds: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address`. Removing the `&[bump]` fixes it for those cases, but breaks it for others!

It seems that the rule is, if bump = 254, omit it. For example this silly fix DOES work for both 254 and 255 bumps (though it still fails for bumps < 254):

```
    if bump == 254 {
        let seeds = &[
            b"whatever".as_ref(),
            &ctx.accounts.someata.key().to_bytes()[..],
            //&[bump]
        ];
        let signers_seeds = &[&seeds[..]];
        invoke_signed(&instruction, &account_infos, signers_seeds)?;
    } else {
         let seeds = &[
            b"whatever".as_ref(),
            &ctx.accounts.someacc.key().to_bytes()[..],
            &[bump]
        ];
        let signers_seeds = &[&seeds[..]];
        invoke_signed(&instruction, &account_infos, signers_seeds)?;
    }
```

But intuitively, the first branch shouldn't work at all, as the bump is missing.

Comment: yes, if `bump` is a `u8`, then `&[bump]` should always be the last item in the seeds array.

Comment: For some key combinations, removing the `&[bump]` from the signer seeds resolves the `Could not create program address` error. In at least one of those cases bump was 245, which is a valid u8, so why?

Comment: then the other data being provided is not resulting in the same calculated bump nonce that you are providing. for pubkeys you can just do `ctx.accounts.someacc.key().as_ref()` and constants, just `"whatever".as_ref()`.  just make sure that the bump nonce you are adding to the ends is the right one for the pda you are providing the seeds for.

Comment: If the front end gets the bump with `[key, bump] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(seeds, id)` then passes it to the ix as an arg e.g. `program.methods.someix(bump).accounts({accounts}).instruction()` then shouldn't that be the correct bump? Again it *works* if the bump is removed from the seed args, for this particular key combination. What is the signers_seeds using for the bump when I omit it?

Comment: you can also get the bump from the `ctx.bumps` map, e.g., if you have a pda in your accounts struct with seeds defined there, if you need to get the bump in the instruction, you can get from `ctx.bumps[<account_struct_prop_name>]`. then you don't have to calc and pass in from the front end.

Answer (score 3):

For the same combination of (optional) input seeds and a program_id, there are multiple bump seeds that can generate valid PDAs (which will have different addresses). When you use `find_program_address` to generate a PDA, it will always return the "canonical bump" (the first bump found that generates a valid PDA).

`find_program_address` finds a valid PDA by adding a `bump` seed (starting from 255) to the list of optional seeds you provide and the program ID, and then calls the `create_program_address` function until a valid PDA is found (retrying with a new bump iterating down from 255). Once found, both the PDA and the bump are returned.

Under the hood, here's what `find_program_address` does (code below is simplified)

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/sdk/program/src/pubkey.rs#L476

```
 pub fn find_program_address(seeds: &[&[u8]], program_id: &Pubkey) -> (Pubkey, u8) {
    Self::try_find_program_address(seeds, program_id)
        .unwrap_or_else(|| panic!("Unable to find a viable program address bump seed"))
}
```

`find_program_address` calls `try_find_program_address`, where a bump (starting from 255) is added and `create_program_address` is called in a loop

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/sdk/program/src/pubkey.rs#L494

```
pub fn try_find_program_address(seeds: &[&[u8]], program_id: &Pubkey) -> Option<(Pubkey, u8)> {

    let mut bump_seed = [std::u8::MAX];
    for _ in 0..std::u8::MAX {
        {
            let mut seeds_with_bump = seeds.to_vec();
            seeds_with_bump.push(&bump_seed);
            match Self::create_program_address(&seeds_with_bump, program_id) {
                Ok(address) => return Some((address, bump_seed[0])),
                Err(PubkeyError::InvalidSeeds) => (),
                _ => break,
            }
        }
        bump_seed[0] -= 1;
    }
    None

}
```

If `create_program_address` generates a valid PDA, the PDA is returned, otherwise the bump seed is decremented by 1 and `create_program_address` is called again with the new bump seed.

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/sdk/program/src/pubkey.rs#L577

```
pub fn create_program_address(
    seeds: &[&[u8]],
    program_id: &Pubkey,
) -> Result<Pubkey, PubkeyError> {

    let mut hasher = crate::hash::Hasher::default();
    for seed in seeds.iter() {
        hasher.hash(seed);
    }
    hasher.hashv(&[program_id.as_ref(), PDA_MARKER]);
    let hash = hasher.result();

    if bytes_are_curve_point(hash) {
        return Err(PubkeyError::InvalidSeeds);
    }

    Ok(Pubkey::new(hash.as_ref()))

}
```

When you use `invoke_signed`, you are providing the list of `signer_seeds` that should generate the valid PDA you need to sign for your CPI.

https://docs.rs/solana-program/1.15.2/solana_program/pubkey/struct.Pubkey.html#method.find_program_address

> Program derived addresses (PDAs) are account keys that only the
> program, program_id, has the authority to sign. The address is of the
> same form as a Solana Pubkey, except they are ensured to not be on the
> ed25519 curve and thus have no associated private key. When performing
> cross-program invocations the program can “sign” for the key by
> calling invoke_signed and passing the same seeds used to generate the
> address, along with the calculated bump seed, which this function
> returns as the second tuple element. The runtime will verify that the
> program associated with this address is the caller and thus authorized
> to be the signer.
>
> Because the program address must not lie on the ed25519 curve, there
> may be seed and program id combinations that are invalid. For this
> reason, an extra seed (the bump seed) is calculated that results in a
> point off the curve. The bump seed must be passed as an additional
> seed when calling invoke_signed.

It could be just by chance that when you exclude the `bump` seed in your example above, that a valid PDA is still being generated. Depending on how you set up your instruction and whether you included checks to validate the PDA/bump, it could explain why your CPI is still going through.

Here's a great article that goes over how PDAs and bumps work: https://www.sec3.dev/blog/pda-bump-seeds

Comment: The naming here is interesting, because in `try_find_program_address` it's called `seeds_with_bump` only AFTER the bump is appended. That seems to imply it wants seeds *without* a bump as input. In Solana's docs elsewhere, they also don't show the bump being passed: https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/calling-between-programs#program-signed-accounts. So it seems canonically excluding the `&[bump]` is the correct answer. It happens too often to be by chance, and the receiver checks the seeds + bump in its init constraints.

Comment: You should not exclude the bump. There's about a 50/50 chance a valid PDA is generated. The bump is what's used to ensure a valid PDA is found. I don't think `invoke_signed` calls `find_program_address`, that's just for background info on PDAs.

Comment: If the wrong seeds were supplied, it would generate a different valid PDA, since the hash would be different. On the front end, `PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(...)` returns key= `some_key`, bump=`254`. That key/bump are sent to the program, which sends it to the CPI. The bump being omitted in signer seeds should end up deriving the wrong address, so how/why does it still generate `some_key` exactly? In the same case, adding the bump back to signer seeds causes it to *fail* to find a valid address. It may be related to https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/21409

Comment: Also, the result of `PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(...)` is the same key/bump as `anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey::find_program_address` on chain. So the bump that is passed or omitted from the signers_seeds is definitively the canonical valid bump for that key.

Comment: What is the instruction that `signers_seeds` is required as a signer for? (which appear to be the seeds for the PDA of the TokenAccount) It looks like you've used `init` to create the TokenAccount (which means you don't need to manually add an instruction to create the TokenAccount) and the auth for the TokenAccount is `some_auth`.